# changing the size of ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon

I have a Jtable. In my Jtable, the first column, I manage to import an image from my directory path store in a text file.

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{
                        new ImageIcon(value[1]),
                        value[2],
                        value[0],
                        value[3],
                        value[4], 
                        });
```

But the image size is too large that it only show part of the image in the limited space in the table column.

How do I resize the image to height = 100 and Width = 100.

Answer (score 4):

Load your Image first, then do

```
Image scaledIm = orignalIm.getScaledInstance(100, 100, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledIm);
```

Or use another rendering hints value

Answer (score 0):

Resizing the icon is not straightforward. You need to use Java's graphics 2D to scale the image.

```
private Image getScaledImage(Image srcImg, int w, int h){
BufferedImage resizedImg = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = resizedImg.createGraphics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    g2.drawImage(srcImg, 0, 0, w, h, null);
    g2.dispose();

    return resizedImg;
    }
```

Comment: The first parameter is a Image class which you can easily get from ImageIcon class. You can use ImageIcon class to load your image file and then simply call getter method to get the image.